# Why are *actual* RS232 transceivers RX thresholds so narrow?

Tags: serial, rs232, logic-level

I'm having horrible communication issues with an RS232 line. It's near a fat load (not good) and it's a printer (so the comm errors are literally visible).

After investigation I actually detected the noise which was somehow triggering the receiver as a start bit. Now for the real question:

I don't know exactly TIA-EIA232F but the ITU-T V.28 (supposedly the same) calls for quite specific signal levels:

- For the generator side:

> when the load open-circuit voltage (EL) is zero, the voltage (V1) at the interchange point shall not be less than 5 volts and not more than 15 volts in magnitude (either positive or negative polarity), for any load resistance (RL) in the range between 3000 ohms and 7000 ohms.

- On the receiver side:

> For data interchange circuits, the signal shall be considered in the binary 1 condition when the voltage (V1) on the interchange circuit measured at the interchange point is more negative than minus 3 volts. The signal shall be considered in the binary 0 condition when the voltage (V1) is more positive than plus 3 volts.

So the standard call for transmitting at 5-15V and recognizing at 3-15V (on both polarities); there are 2V headroom and that should be fine for the expected circuit lengths.

> The region between plus 3 volts and minus 3 volts is defined as the transition region.

Now, it's not quite clear what the receiver is expected to do with a signal in the transition region. It only says what the transmitter have to do (do not wobble inside the transition and some slew rate limiting)

I would expect something like a schmitt trigger structure or at least a strong threshold at +3V.

Nope. Most of the transceiver I've seen around simply receive more or less as an LVTTL gate (often actually 0.6V as low and 2.4V as high). In practice *almost no noise immunity*. At least they have drive strength.

Anybody know why is that? It's simply one of these 'it isn't allowed but it isn't forbidden either so we'll do that way since it's cheaper?'

Comment: Surely LVTTL doesn’t handle negative voltages, are you confusing RS232 with TTL?  In any case, a transition between positive and negative must pass through zero so the identification of a bit must also have time constraints in addition to voltage.

Comment: It seems that the transceiver simply *ignores* negative voltages, it only needs to go below 0.6V to be officially declared low (instead of going all the way down to -3V as the standard says). The real issue is that it isn't defined in the standard how the receiver shold behave between -3 and +3 so most transceiver around have horrible noise immunity

Comment: There is nothing stopping you building and using a higher quality receiver.

Comment: more than a higher quality receiver (in the printer!) I'll need a more robust transmitter. And better cabling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mentioned in the classic MC1489 as the reason why thresholds even with hysteresis are both above ground. It is to detect the 0V open circuit as the OFF or Logic 1 condition for idle.

If the threshold was such that the line needs to go negative before transition is detected and positive to detect another transition, you could not detect a break in the line when it goes to 0V.

Simply because the specs allow any implementation within the specs so it is usually done in the simplest possible way.
I don't see that it would be required that a disconnected or turned off transmitter needs to be understood as OFF or idle condition by the receiver, but it does make sense in practice.

The drivers need to put the threshold somewhere in the region between +3 and -3 volts, and that is why there is the monotonicity and speed requirement. And the receivers do implement hysteresis to address noise. So any positive voltage between around 1.5V will suffice.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the 1489 datasheet (which has a schematic) and in fact it's more of a common collector (triple!) buffer than a comparator. The hysteresis is a simple collector stage feedback (the 1489A part is different on that). I'm probably just too spoiled from differential signaling. As for the 'disconnect' behaviour there is an historical and a modern usage and the standard allows both of them.